# Make Section, Subsection, and Subsubsection Titles Flush with Top Margin with Double Space

Tags: spacing, margins, titlesec, vertical-spacing, section-titles

I am trying to get the subsection title flush with the top margin when it appears on a new page. I was able to get all the section headings flush with the top margin by using the the `\setstretch{1}` command in the `\titleformat{\section}`. The same trick doesn't work for the subsection because I am using `hang` for them instead of `display` so it has the unwanted affect of removing the double spacing.

In the second image, how can I get the subsection title to be flush with the top margin just like the section on the first page? I have tried `\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-.5in}{0pt}` but this messes up the subsection on the first page and it also **doesn't** do anything for subsections that appear on a new page.

Some things to note: I do not want to mess up the long subsection heading that is on the first page. Also, this is a problem that I am trying to solve for a large document. Also, I am pretty committed to the titlesec package at this point. Finally, I have the same exact issue with subsubsection so I am looking for a solution that will also work with that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in, margin=1in, showframe=true]{geometry} % Set paper size.

%Set font to Arial font
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}%new page for each section
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering}{\setstretch{1}SECTION \thesection}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\centering}{\thesubsection}{\widthof{\space}}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%Removes spacing around section titles
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}%Removes spacing around subsection titles


\begin{document}
\raggedright % Flush left
\setlength\parindent{0.5in}%Indent the text. Must be after raggedright.
\setstretch{2} % Double space the entire document (used to be \doublespacing)
\section{LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE }
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE }


\newpage
\subsection{LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE  LONG TITLE }
\end{document}
```

First page: The section is flush with the top margin. [image: In the first page, the section is flush with the top margin.]

Second page: The subsection is not flush with the top margin like the section on the first page. [image: Here, on page 2 you can see that the subsection is title is not flush with the top margin like the first page.]